# ten image in one row using uikit

Tags: html, css, uikit

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div  class="follow uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-expand@s uk-child-width-1-2   uk-child-height-1-2 "  uk-grid>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?heli" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image2" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?everest" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image3" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?cat" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image4" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?nepal" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image5" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?china" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image6" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?japan" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image7" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?annapurna" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image8" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?food" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image9" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?coffee" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image10" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?chocolate" alt="" ></a></div>

    </div>
```

This code is written pure uikit 3 framework. I  used grid to divided the section .In desktop mode i want to show only 10 images and when i changed desktop mode to mobile mode , it only show 2 images . it working fine . but when i changed to mobile  mode it shows only two images and  extra white space is also coming . i don't want that  extra white space. i just want two images with full of width . 
I need to used  150x150  image resolution.

Comment: use bigger images, try 300x300

Comment: @ Temani Afif thank you for your suggestion but i need used the same image resolution. Please suggest another way to solve the problem

Comment: Can't you use Slick.js with responsive breakpoint?

Comment: in this case use `width:100%` with the image but they will render badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the alignment to remove the space between and keep everything centred:

```css
@media (max-width:640px) {
  .follow > div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    text-align:right;
  }
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div  class="follow uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-expand@s uk-child-width-1-2   uk-child-height-1-2 "  uk-grid>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?heli" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image2" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?everest" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image3" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?cat" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image4" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?nepal" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image5" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?china" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image6" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?japan" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image7" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?annapurna" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image8" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?food" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image9" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?coffee" alt="" ></a></div>
        <div><a href="#modal-media-image10" uk-toggle><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/150x150/?chocolate" alt="" ></a></div>

    </div>
```